# How to perform statistical analysis for a nls function in R?

Tags: r, analysis, nls

`fm0 <- nls(exp(y) ~ exp(a*log(x)), moisture, start = c(a = 1, b = 1))`

This is my code to obtain the starting conditions for my locarithmic model. How can I check the residuals on the reliability of this model for my dataset? Or what am I missing?
I already tried

`summary(fm0)`

`plot(fm0)`

Thank you for your help Cyril

Comment: We are missing any scientific context for this question. What procedures are typically done in your (unstated) field of research?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: @Cyril why not use `lm(y ~ a * log(x))`?